# How do I upload a File type in Dynamics 365 using c#

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a file abc.jpeg that I would like to upload and attach to an entity prefix_account and the image property is called prefix_accountimage. What is the best approach to do this with any file size. Do I need to use InitializeFileBlocksUploadRequest? Does someone have a full working example of code that can accomplish this?

Comment: which language you are using? C# and the official SDK or Web API?

Comment: [Found a sample by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/file-attributes?tabs=sdk#example-net-c-code-for-full-file-upload-using-web-api)